# Unable to access TextEditor from XCUIApplication in XCTest

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcuitest

I am trying to write a UI test for our app that uses the new `TextEditor` view.

```swift
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()

let textEditor = app.<accessor>["Editor"]
textEditor.typeText("Hello, world")
```

I cannot find anywhere what this accessor should be. Predictably, `textFields` doesn't work, and neither does `textViews`.

Is there a generic accessor I could use instead?

EDIT: The `textViews` accessor does in fact work.

Comment: can you use recorder and click it to find a way to access it?
also, textFields should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to tap to make it focused before entering text, but it looks there is a bug in Xcode 13 Simulator (`TextEditor` is out of safe area by default), because all works *only* if `TextEditor` has a defined frame.

Here is a demo (prepared with Xcode 13 / iOS 15)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var text = "Test Text"

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .accessibilityIdentifier("TextEditor")
            .frame(maxHeight: 400)                   // << limit !!
    }
}
```

and now UT:

```
    func testTextEditor() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        let result = app.textViews["TextEditor"]
        XCTAssertTrue(result.exists)
        XCTAssertEqual(result.value as? String ?? "", "Test Text")

        result.tap()     // << here

        result.typeText("New value")
        XCTAssertTrue(String(result.value as? String ?? "").hasPrefix("New valueTest Text"))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tap the field or view into focus before attempting to type in it.